# Click once deployment and Unity assemblies

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I have the "unable to install blah blah.....Unity 2.0.414.0 must be installed into the GAC first"  installation error.

I have set all my Unity related dlls to "copy local"
I have set the dlls to "include" 
I have uninstalled Unity 2.1 and Ent Lib 5.1 (in attempt to remove items that might be in GAC)
I am actually referencing 2.0.515.0 and not the version mentioned in the message.

What am I doing wrong! I am aware that I COULD install the dlls in the GAC, but I want to install them in a private location, along with my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
So you can stop the click once deployment setup checking the GAC if you ensure *all* assemblies which are marked as pre-requisites, are set to include/required.  This is not ideal if you want to rely upon assemblies in the GAC but at least you can be sure of what versions of assemblies your application will be using. And if the pre-reqs now included are not signed then you can not sign the deployment which WILL be an issue where verification is required.
The actual problem, I am sure, is related to previous versions of an assembly I have used for Unity still living in the GAC.

Comment: How can you stop that?